# Menu invisible in Safari

Tags: css, safari, invisible

On this [website:](http://99-ideas.de) I've the following problem in Safari:
When clicking the 1st time on "KUNDEN" in the navigation, the complete header is invisible. In the dev console I saw, that the content of the header is already loaded - also in the source code.
But the content is not appearing until reloading the page or marking everything (STRG+A).

Does anybody have an idea, why this is happening? Could it be a Typo3 bug?
look at that screenshot:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/hNOqLw0.png]

I'm using Safari 6.0.5 on Mac 10.8.4.

Comment: Whenever you have cross-brower problems, make sure your HTML is valid:  See errors:  http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2F99-ideas.de%2Fhallo.html&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to close a `div` tag.

Line 72:

```
<div style="clear:both" </div></header><div id="content">
```

should be:

```
<div style="clear:both"></div></header><div id="content">
```

See all W3C Validation errors:

http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2F99-ideas.de%2Fhallo.html&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Comment: temporary I removed all errors - so the validator said everythings fine. But this error still appears in Safari..